# how to define nested routes + ember not rendering template for nested route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a rails 4 + emberjs application. I am trying to create nested routes in ember. I am refering the 'nested routes' section from http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/. All the defiend routes for post work fine but the routes for 'comments' dont work. My current ember routes are as:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'posts', ->
    @route 'edit', 
      path: '/:id/edit'
    @route 'show',
      path: '/:id'
    @resource "comments", 
      path: '/:post_id/comments'
    , ->
      @route "new"
```

I have a CommentsNewRoute file as:

```
App.CommentsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend                                                                                                               
  model: (params) ->
    post: @store.find 'post', params.post_id
```

And have a template as comments.handlebars containing {{outlet}} and comments/new.handlebars containing 'Hello World'. Have places comments.handlebars and new.handlebars inside posts templates as well as at the same level. Still, none are rendered.

the link-to helper is as:

```
{{#link-to 'comments.new' id classNames='pull-right' }}Add New Comment{{/link-to}}
```

The problems are that 1) The params in the CommentsNewRoute is an empty object and doesnt contain post_id. 2) The new comments template isnt rendered when i click a link that points to '/#/posts/2/comments/new'. 3) How can i display the post's objects data on the new comments page? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show us your link-to helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic segment values are only available to the route that the dynamic segment belongs to.

Which means you should load the post on `App.CommentsRoute` and reuse it on `App.CommentsNewRoute`, [see the example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dizewuraru)

```
App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('post', params.post_id); 
    }
});

App.CommentsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.modelFor('comments'); 
    }
});
```

[More info](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/nested-resources-and-dynamic-segments/5111/2)